# Port 22 connection refused

Tags: ssh

I’m trying to copy a disk image over ssh to my local machine using this tutorial on [linodes website](https://www.linode.com/docs/migrate-to-linode/disk-images/copying-a-disk-image-over-ssh).

I know this could be posted on their support forum, but im convinced its in the general realm of *unix knowledge.

I’ve followed all the steps and I can get int Finnix (custom editor), checked the disk images and now I want to download it via SSH to my local machine. I keep getting:

I can already ssh into the remote server, its when im in Finnix.

root@hvc0~# ....

```
ssh root@xxxxxxxxx port 22: connection refused
```

after typing

```
ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx "dd if=/dev/xvdb " | dd of=/home/linode.img
```

So I’ve re-written the firewall rules, checked for memory leaks, reset root password, logged in via the ajax console on their site, pings, disk space and still no luck.

Any suggestions on why this is?

Comment: did you install `ssh` server on your machine? Did you start it?

Comment: I can already ssh into the remote server. I've enabled remote login on my machine but isn't that only if I want to access another mac / make mine accessible to another mac?

Comment: @pqnet : He is able to login to the remote system through `ssh`.That means `ssh` server is already there in his machine.

Comment: @Learn `port 22: connection refused` is pretty clear. There is no `ssh` daemon (or is blocked by a firewall) on machine `root@xxx.xx.xx.xx`. Read my answer below for my best guess. Also, the line "I can already ssh into the remote server, its when im in Finnix." was added after my comment

Comment: `tdpdump` or `tshark` is your friend. Run it at both ends to confirm first that the packets are leaving and then second to confirm that they arrive. If the packets arrive, is there a response and does the response arrive back where the whole thing started. Checking this will give you a lot of clues.

Comment: Are you going from the same client when you SSH into the remote server normally and when you get the error? If not, it could be a firewall rule that only allows SSH from specific clients.

Answer (score 1):

the command

```
ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx "dd if=/dev/xvdb " | dd of=/home/linode.img
```

needs to be typed on the machine where you want to save the backup (the one having `/home/linode.img`), and `xxx.xx.xx.xx` needs to be the machine you want to backup. After reading better I feel like the problem is that you are doing the opposite.

`scp` is not the right command in this case, since he wants to copy directly from the server hard disk device (in opposition to copy only one file). This is why the guide suggested that command instead.

Comment: Might be improved to include any guesses on what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy a file, use *scp* instead. The syntax is pretty simple:

```
scp remote-user@ip-remote-server:path/file.img .
```

This command needs to be executed from your local machine, replacing all the variables above. You can use variations of the syntax and find many examples in *scp* manpage.

Comment: You're right, but "connection refused" precludes ssh, scp, and sftp.

Comment: Do you have *openssh-server* package in both machines?

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue and there may be reasons to run dd rather than (s)cp.

Answer (score -1):

Using `ssh` you can login to the remote system but you can't copy any files from the remote system.To copy file from the remote system you can use `scp` command from your local system as below .

`scp remote-user@remote-system-ip:/some/remote/dir/file /local/system/dir`

and if you want to copy directory from the remote system then you use `-r` option to `scp` .

Comment: Thanks Learn. The thing is its via linode website so I'm guessing it uses its own syntax as per above. I tried your option and could resolve IP (which it can normally)